# Change a synonym lemma according to a POS Tag value

Tags: c++, python, nlp, wordnet

I need to replace a a word with its synonym in a sentence.
For that, I POS Tag each word in the sentence and for the word I wish to replace I find the best matching synonym Wordnet synset.
Now, what I am missing is the ability to take the synonym lemma and change it according to the original word POS Tag value.
I was wondering whether anyone knows of a library in C++ or Python that I can take a lemma and the POS Tag value and change the lemma according to the input POS Tag...
For instance, the sentence:
"The grand jurry commented"

The word 'commented' was pos tagged as 'VBD' (past tense)
I can take the synonym: 'remark' and need to change it to 'remarked' -> as 'VBD' is a past tense of the verb

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a morphological generator.  See a list of tools for English here:

http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English

I'm not familiar with all the tools, but for simple English inflection, morphg works well (note that it's for non-commercial use).